# Yii Bootstrap Select 2 : Select a choice once

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, jquery-select2

I'm using select2, and i've been reading its [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) , so I have this select2

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2', array(
                        'name' => 'Select',
                        'options' => array(
                            'tags' => $tags,
                        ),
                        'htmlOptions'=>array(
                            'style'=>'width:10px'
                        ),
                        'asDropDownList' => false,
                    ));
```

let's say $tags contain values **red,blue,green** and I set it to multiple true. I could select them all, but the problem is I could select red twice, or blue twice. Is there a way to set the condition that if a choice is already selected, it may no longer appear in the list of choices?

Comment: could you elaborate please, do you have only 1 select2 field or multiple and dont want them to be selectable in more then one

Comment: ye exactly this one ^

Comment: which one ? i gave you a choice between 2 options

Comment: i have 1 select2 field which has an array of tags. but it can only select one tag, no repeats.

Comment: Ah so you want to be able to select duplicate tags ?

Comment: no...for example i have red,blue,green. i should only be able to select green once, red once or blue once.

Comment: are you sure all the colours only show up once ?

Comment: no, that's what i'm trying to acheive

Comment: have you actually looked at my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that every tag is only in the list once, you can filter out duplicates with :

```
'data' => array_filter($data),
```

I have never used TbSelect2, However I used ESelect2 before.
There is [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/) specificly for yii's widget of ESelect2

this is how you correctly set the multiple parameter :

```
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'name'=>'Select',
  'data'=>$data,
  'htmlOptions'=>array(
    'multiple'=>'multiple',
    'style'=>'width:10px'
  ),
  'asDropDownList' => false,
));
```